# Clicking links on the website to get contents in the bubbles with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to get the course information on http://bulletin.iit.edu/graduate/colleges/science/applied-mathematics/master-data-science/#programrequirementstext.

In my code, I tried to first click on each course, next get the description in the bubble, and then close the bubble as it may overlay on top of other course links.

My problem is that I couldn't get the description in the bubble and some course links were still skipped though I tried to avoid it by closing the bubble.

Any idea about how to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
info = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://bulletin.iit.edu/graduate/colleges/science/applied-mathematics/master-data-science/#programrequirementstext')
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(2, 46):
        try: 
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="programrequirementstextcontainer"]/table['+str(i)+']/tbody/tr['+str(j)+']/td[1]/a').click()
            info.append(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div')[0].text)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lfjsbubbleclose"]').click()
            time.sleep(3)
        except: pass 


  [1]: http://bulletin.iit.edu/graduate/colleges/science/applied-mathematics/master-data-science/#programrequirementstext
```

Comment: Why you put range 46 in `for j in range(2, 46):`even though there are no 46 element on the page ? Better to make once xpath with combination and grab all those and loop them to extract description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have put static range in for loop even though all the combinations of i and j index count in your xpath doesn't find any element on your application.

I would suggest better to go with finding all element on your webpage using single locator and loop trough to get descriptions from bubble.

Use below code:

```
course_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.sc_courselist a.bubblelink.code")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
for course in course_list:
    try:
        print("grabbing info of course : ", course.text)
        course.click()
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.courseblockdesc")))
        info.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.courseblockdesc>p').text)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "lfjsbubbleclose")))
        driver.find_element_by_id('lfjsbubbleclose').click()
    except:
        print("error while grabbing info")

print(info)
```

As it require some time to load the content in bubble so you should introduce explicit wait in your script until bubble content get completely visible and then grab it.

import below package for using wait in above code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Please note, this code grab all the courses description from bubble. Let me know if you are looking for some specific not all.

Answer (score 1):

To load the bubble, the website makes an ajax call.

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def course(course_code):
    data = {"page":"getcourse.rjs","code":course_code}

    res = requests.get("http://bulletin.iit.edu/ribbit/index.cgi", data=data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    result = {}
    result["description"] = soup.find("div", class_="courseblockdesc").text.strip()
    result["title"] = soup.find("div", class_="coursetitle").text.strip()
    return result
```

Output for `course("CS 522")`

````
{'description': 'Continued exploration of data mining algorithms. More sophisticated algorithms such as support vector machines will be studied in detail. Students will continuously study new contributions to the field. A large project will be required that encourages students to push the limits of existing data mining techniques.',
 'title': 'Advanced Data Mining'}```
````